# JSON Schema validation is not working

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json response like below. In the views array may or may not contain actions array.
[image]
In the reponse If any of view array contains actions object , then i have to validate that actions data with json schema(`schema1.json`)
And in the schema i mentioned the action propertes like(`type,label,localizedlabel`) as required ones.
But when I modify key or value type of this type,label,localizedlabel in the response does not output any errors.
Tested via( https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/). what wrong with my schema?
How can i validate actions object only whenever it present inside any of view array?

schema1.json

```
{
  "$id": "",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$id": "/items",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "$id": "/items/properties/name",
        "type": "string",
        "title": "The Name Schema ",
        "default": "",
        "examples": [
          "Preview"
        ]
      },
      "displayOrder": {
        "$id": "/items/properties/displayOrder",
        "type": "integer",
        "title": "The Displayorder Schema ",
        "default": 0,
        "examples": [
          1
        ]
      },
      "actions": {
        "$id": "/items/properties/actions",
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "$id": "/items/properties/actions/items",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "$id": "/items/properties/actions/items/properties/type",
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Type Schema ",
              "default": "",
              "examples": [
                "watch"
              ]
            },
            "label": {
              "$id": "/items/properties/actions/items/properties/label",
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Label Schema ",
              "default": "",
              "examples": [
                "Watch"
              ]
            },
            "localizedLabel": {
              "$id": "/items/properties/actions/items/properties/localizedLabel",
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "ENG": {
                  "$id": "/items/properties/actions/items/properties/localizedLabel/properties/ENG",
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "The Eng Schema ",
                  "default": "",
                  "examples": [
                    "Watch"
                  ]
                },
                "ESP": {
                  "$id": "/items/properties/actions/items/properties/localizedLabel/properties/ESP",
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "The Esp Schema ",
                  "default": "",
                  "examples": [
                    "Ver"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "type",
            "label",
            "localizedLabel"
          ]
        }
      },
      "localizedName": {
        "$id": "/items/properties/localizedName",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "ENG": {
            "$id": "/items/properties/localizedName/properties/ENG",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The Eng Schema ",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "Preview"
            ]
          },
          "ESP": {
            "$id": "/items/properties/localizedName/properties/ESP",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The Esp Schema ",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "Adelanto"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "actions"
    ]
  }
}
```

response json

```
[{

        "season": 2017,
        "teamData": {
            "awayTeam": {
                "id": 6,
                "city": "Dallas",
                "name": "Mavericks",
                "abbr": "DAL",
                "color": "#0B51A1"
            },
            "homeTeam": {
                "id": 8,
                "city": "Detroit",
                "name": "Pistons",
                "abbr": "DET",
                "color": "#990300"
            }
        },
        "views": [{
                "name": "Preview",
                "displayOrder": 1,
                "groups": [{
                        "type": "static",
                        "displayOrder": 1,
                        "tiles": [{
                                "context": "event",
                                "collection": "event",
                                "auditType": "pregame-preview",
                                "displayOrder": 1,
                                "_id": "5ac58ea21ee2112b33291f1c",
                                "eventId": 2018040608,
                                "dimensions": {
                                    "width": 372,
                                    "height": 375
                                },
                                "tileId": "36b154e719d7d8397da487cbc4e5f7d1",
                                "renderTime": "2018-04-05T02:49:05+00:00",
                                "dataTime": "2018-04-05T02:48:58+00:00",
                                "dataStamp": 1522896538,
                                "location": "http://test.com/2018040608/static/pre-event/pregame-preview/1522896538.png",
                                "tile_type": "static"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [{
                        "type": "watch",
                        "label": "Watch",
                        "localizedLabel": {
                            "ENG": "Watch",
                            "ESP": "Ver"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "type": "record",
                        "label": "Record",
                        "localizedLabel": {
                            "ENG": "Record",
                            "ESP": "Grabar"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "type": "tile_overlay",
                        "label": "Current Standings",
                        "tili": {
                            "context": "event",
                            "collection": "event",
                            "auditType": "full-standings",
                            "_id": "5ac6f9de2ccaf768d092c918",
                            "eventId": 2018040608,
                            "dimensions": {
                                "width": 1140,
                                "height": 660
                            },
                            "tileId": "852f92537e68dc99b54f1228459ec9ef",
                            "renderTime": "2018-04-06T04:38:54+00:00",
                            "dataTime": "2018-04-06T04:38:52+00:00",
                            "dataStamp": 1522989532,
                            "location": "http://test.com/2018040608/static/pre-event/full-standings/1522989532.png"
                        },
                        "localizedLabel": {
                            "ENG": "Current Standings",
                            "ESP": "Posición actual"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "type": "favorite",
                        "label": "Favorite",
                        "localizedLabel": {
                            "ENG": "Favorite",
                            "ESP": "Favorito"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "localizedName": {
                    "ENG": "Preview",
                    "ESP": "Adelanto"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Team Stats",
                "displayOrder": 2,
                "groups": [{
                        "type": "static",
                        "displayOrder": 1,
                        "tiles": [{
                                "context": "event",
                                "collection": "event",
                                "auditType": "pregame-team_stats",
                                "displayOrder": 1,
                                "_id": "5ac6755a4f82eb58a5eae6a6",
                                "eventId": 2018040608,
                                "dimensions": {
                                    "width": 372,
                                    "height": 510
                                },
                                "tileId": "1302dc16c9fe68c3e6edadd98afce2bc",
                                "renderTime": "2018-04-05T19:13:30+00:00",
                                "dataTime": "2018-04-05T19:13:28+00:00",
                                "dataStamp": 1522955608,
                                "location": "http://test.com/2018040608/static/pre-event/pregame-team_stats/1522955608.png",
                                "tile_type": "static"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "localizedName": {
                    "ENG": "Team Stats",
                    "ESP": "Estadísticas del equipo"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Leaders",
                "displayOrder": 3,
                "groups": [{
                        "type": "static",
                        "displayOrder": 1,
                        "tiles": [{
                                "context": "event",
                                "collection": "event",
                                "auditType": "pregame-leaders",
                                "displayOrder": 1,
                                "_id": "5ac26eb31ee2112b3328b00c",
                                "eventId": 2018040608,
                                "dimensions": {
                                    "width": 372,
                                    "height": 510
                                },
                                "tileId": "96abc24c47d61327426ef2b24281acbf",
                                "renderTime": "2018-04-02T17:55:57+00:00",
                                "dataTime": "2018-04-02T17:55:54+00:00",
                                "dataStamp": 1522691754,
                                "location": "http://test.com/2018040608/static/pre-event/pregame-leaders/1522691754.png",
                                "tile_type": "static"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "localizedName": {
                    "ENG": "Leaders",
                    "ESP": "Líderes"
                }
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: There is a keyword 'additionalProperties' that can be used to limit the set of keys. Adding it after the 'required' would catch any typo in keys. Would that fit what you need ?

Comment: could you please clarify how to set additionalProperties in the above schema to satisfy my requirement? i tried but it was not working...so please

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your schema. It should do what you need if used properly. Because it only describes the "views" part of the schema you would need to iterate through your response and pass just the "views" part of each item to the validator one at a time.

Or, you could add enough of the response structure to the schema to validate everything at once.  Then you could just pass your whole response to the validator.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "views": { "$ref": "schema1.json" }
    }
  }
}
```